# Safari shows buttons as invisible but still clickable (Bootstrap HTML)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just am completely clueless here, I've never seen any issue like this before. I have two buttons, one says 'Quote' the other says 'Order'. On chrome these buttons work perfectly and are amazingly responsive when the window is resized the button look does exactly what I want it to, the same goes for firefox, it just works great.

Safari on the other hand is a totally different story, the buttons are there and clickable and fully functional, however they are invisible. I just see nothing...

Here's the HTML code for the buttons:

```
<a ng-hide="shoppingCartHeader" href="#" ng-click="checkout({{project.id}})" id="btn-complete-btn" class="btn btn-info">Order</a>
        <a style="margin-right:20px;" ng-hide="shoppingCartHeader" href="#" ng-click="quoteRequest({{project.id}})" id="btn-quote-btn" class="btn btn-warning">Quote</a>
```

Here's the CSS code for the buttons:

```
#btn-complete-btn
{
position:fixed;
right:5px;
bottom:5px;
z-index: 99004;
}

#btn-quote-btn
{
position:fixed;
right:55px;
bottom:5px;
z-index: 99004;
}
```

You don't see them on Safari but you can still click on them and they work and seem to have the correct sizes... They're just invisible.

The difference between chrome and safari is that the buttons are just invisible on Safari but they can still be clicked on, even if the window is resized....

Is there a work around for this on Safari???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ofrzrm/ Works fine in the Fiddle. Something else is going on. I've noticed Safari doesn't add missing close tags as some other browsers do. Are you sure your HTML is in tact?

Comment: It's flawless on Chrome and Firefox, is there a way to inspect element on Safari?

Comment: Try using the Safari Web Inspector - here's a link to more information on it: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I'm not expert at how to do that, but if you simply view source in Firefox it will highlight tags in red that may have issues like no closing tag, etc. Sometimes that a simple fix. Can you show us your live page or past full HTML somewhere? I've had an issue in Safari where a div filled too much of the page because Chrome and FF assumed where to add the close tag and Safari did not. No idea if this is the issue, but just saying, one possibility as the code you posted has no issues.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, which led me to this page.
**Let me share with you what worked for me.**
I created a new class to assign to button tags.
It did no harm in Chrome.

```
 <style>
  .safaribtn {background-color:silver;}
</style>
```